# execute url in java

Tags: java, api, sms

I have an web app using JSF 2.0 where I need to send SMS through API I have after registration.

For API I have URL like below.

```
http://www.sms.com/mywebservice.asmx?userId=123&senderMobNum=1234,5678&text=test message.
```

Any idea how can I execute this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you say execute this URL, it means making a HTTP call to this URL I assume, looking at the URL looks like you want to make a GET request, you can use [commons-httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) for this purpose

Comment: I want to execute URL... It will send then SMS to 1234 & 5678

Comment: let me try with link you provided and get back to you...